# Vuex: form binding for element of array of objects?

Tags: vuejs2, vuex, vuex-modules

Vuex has pleasantly nice documents.
In which we see how to do [2-way binding](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/forms.html):

```js
// component.vue
...,
computed: {
  message: {
    get () {
      return this.$store.state.obj.message
    },
    set (value) {
      this.$store.commit('updateMessage', value)
    }
  }
},
...
```

this works great but what if you wanted to bind the property of an object of an array?

e.g.

```
// state.js
...
listOfThings: [
    {
        text: 'lets bind this',
        value: 0
    },
    {
        text: 'and this is in the $store',
        value: 20
    }
]
```

and lets say we use `mapState`, then we might want to have a component for the list of things that users can update the store with:

or, is the only way to achieve this by making the form binding for an object its own component and passing in, via a prop, the index and in the form component use

```
 text: {
    get () {
      return this.$store.state.listOfThings[this.i].text
    },
    set (value) {
      this.$store.commit('updateText', {i, text: value})
    }
  }
```

Comment: Creating a comp per object and using its props will work.
TBH - I don't fully understand your last example - are you trying to make a generic computed prop to ALL of the objects?

Comment: @aviad no, just am lazy and don’t want to write get / set for each property of the objects in the array. So was hoping for a shorthand like ‘v-model=“arr[i]”’ :p